# How to view updated model object if transaction performed in external method

Tags: python, django

Here is the scenario I am running into:

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
print 'Original Balance is %s' user.balance

### this commits the new balance in a transaction in another file/function
user.pay(1.05) # this function does a user.balance=new_balance;user.save()

print 'New Balance is %s' user.balance
```

Here is the `pay()` method:

```
def pay(self, amount):
    """
    Withdraw `amount` USD from this credit card.
    The user's balance goes UP!!!
    """
    user = self.user
    environment_url = braintree.Configuration.environment._Environment__server.lower()
    print '>>> MODE: %s| AMOUNT: %s' % (environment_url, amount)

    with transaction.commit_manually():
        try:
            sale = braintree.Transaction.sale({
                    "amount": "%.2f" % float(amount),
                    "customer_id": self.braintree_id,
                })
            if sale.is_success:
                user.balance = float(user.balance) + amount
                user.save()
                payment = Payment.objects.create(
                   user=user,
                   amount_in=amount,
                   status=PAID,
                   transaction_id=sale.transaction.id,
                   domain=braintree.Configuration.environment._Environment__server,
                   data = str(sale),
                   reason='Deposit via api of $%.2f' % amount)
                History.objects.create(user=self.user, history_type=HISTORY_TYPE_DEPOSIT, obj_class_name='Payment', obj_pk=payment.pk)
                transaction.commit()
                return sale
```

How would I update the values of the user object, instead of using the values that are pulled/cached from the first `.get()` ?

Comment: Source code for `deposit_funds` is necessary to answer.

Comment: Note that `deposit_funds` is now the `pay` method.

Comment: What is self.user? If pay is a method on user, and you want to update that object, user should be self.

Comment: `self.user` is the user. The `pay` method is on another Model, that of `CreditCard`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `@transaction.commit_manually` decorator. Read [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/transactions/#module-django.db.transaction) about transactions
 So you need to move your pay call to a view using `@transaction.commit_manually` decorator

```
    @transaction.commit_manually
    def viewfunc(request):
        user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
        print 'Original Balance is %s' user.balance

        ### this commits the new balance in a transaction in another file/function
        user.pay(1.05)
        transaction.commit()
        print 'New Balance is %s' user.balance
```

Then, your pay function.

```
    def pay(self, amount):
        """
        Withdraw `amount` USD from this credit card.
        The user's balance goes UP!!!
        """
        user = self.user
        environment_url = braintree.Configuration.environment._Environment__server.lower()
        print '>>> MODE: %s| AMOUNT: %s' % (environment_url, amount)


                sale = braintree.Transaction.sale({
                        "amount": "%.2f" % float(amount),
                        "customer_id": self.braintree_id,
                    })
                if sale.is_success:
                    user.balance = float(user.balance) + amount
                    user.save()
                    payment = Payment.objects.create(
                       user=user,
                       amount_in=amount,
                       status=PAID,
                       transaction_id=sale.transaction.id,
                       domain=braintree.Configuration.environment._Environment__server,
                       data = str(sale),
                       reason='Deposit via api of $%.2f' % amount)
                    History.objects.create(user=self.user, history_type=HISTORY_TYPE_DEPOSIT, obj_class_name='Payment', obj_pk=payment.pk)

                    return sale
```

> The recommended way to handle transactions in Web requests is to tie
>   them to the request and response phases via Django’s
>   TransactionMiddleware.
>
> It works like this: When a request starts, Django starts a
>   transaction. If the response is produced without problems, Django
>   commits any pending transactions. If the view function produces an
>   exception, Django rolls back any pending transactions.

Comment: That is already happening in the `user.deposit_funds()` method, which occurs in a separate function/file.

Comment: @David542 why is your question then ?

Comment: @David542 then in your `user.deposit_funds()` method, you are not saving the new value, because in your second print, you should get your new value.

Comment: it is saved in a transaction.

Comment: You need to show the actual source code instead of obfuscating your problem with what you think is happening. What you are describing doing should already work.

Comment: @levi I like this solution and it does 'solve' the question that I asked. However, I have to keep the transaction on the Model method, as I have several views, functions, and external API calls that are relying on it. Given that, would it work if I just re-did the `.get()` method?

Answer (score 0):

```
    user.balance = new_balance
    user.save()
```

That should do it ;)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @BhargavRao You are late to the ballgame. The question has been edited numerous times and when both of these answers were posted, they were not only relevant, they answered the question and looked like the correct answer to the question as written.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Brother you are above 2k rep, you know about review queues. :( (Better leave this here)